# Margin auto fails IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

if you [check my website](http://personalizatumovil.es/) with the browser Chrome you can see how the div called .bg-content works fine with this style:

```
.bg-content {
    max-width: 605px;
    height: 149px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 62px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

But if you open my website with Internet Explorer 11 the div .bg-content is not centered, he is floating to left.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

it doesn't work because the max-width;

Try this:

```
.bg-content {
    width: 605px;
    height: 149px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 62px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: i added 
   content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 37%;
    height: 4px;
    background: #ffcc11;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
but its not working, its coming left side only

Comment: Setting `display: block` with a `max-width` worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

You should use

`width: 100%;`

in your .bg-content element

Example:
[IE11 max-width & margin auto fix](https://codepen.io/alexandrecanijo/pen/gKvmLp)

Comment: This is the most elegant answer

Answer (score 9):

The hack I always use for Internet Explorer (mostly for the older versions though), is setting the parent container `text-align: center;` and the container itself `text-align: left;`.

I have taken a look at your website, and the parent container seems to not have a default width. Please try setting it on `width: 100%;`. I tried that in the run-time environment, and it seemed to work.

Comment: Upvote for `width: 100%`.  Works as expected with `max-width` so long as `width: 100%` is also declared.

Answer (score 2):

for a fixed position element :

```
left: 0;
right: 0:
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

For absolute position element you can use this

```
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0 auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 200px; // change this as you want
 width: 450px; // change this as you want
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
```